# Child Element Focus State Changes Styling of Parent Element SASS @at-root

Tags: css, sass, accessibility

When the child element span.icon-hamburger in the below code receives a :focus state, I am wanting to change the styling of the li element. Using a SASS solution, I read that @at-root could work here. I am unable to find a SASS solution for this use-case using @at-root, however. What are your thoughts for this use-case?

**HTML:**

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <span class="icon-hamburger"></span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

**CSS/SASS:**

```
.icon-hamburger:focus {
  @at-root ol li #{&} {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no solution for IE and Edge but for Chrome and Firefox you can use :focus-within CSS pseudo-class.

> The :focus-within CSS pseudo-class represents an element that has
>   received focus or contains an element that has received focus. In
>   other words, it represents an element that is itself matched by the
>   :focus pseudo-class or has a descendant that is matched by :focus.
>   (This includes descendants in shadow trees.)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within

Answer (score 0):

From [this excellent answer by Dan Herbert:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/2014893)

> There is currently no way to select the parent of an element in CSS.
>
> If there was a way to do it, it would be in either of the current CSS selectors specs:
>
> [Selectors Level 3 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors)
>
> [CSS 2.1 Selectors Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching)
>
> In the meantime, you'll have to resort to JavaScript if you need to select a parent element.

N.B., there's some discussion over the possibility of doing so in CSS4.